# According the theory of general relativity, what is the role of causality in the changes of the curvature of spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, causality

In Einstein's equations the curvature of spacetime and energy-momentum-pressure density are correlated. Is it clear when changes in matter energy density affect causally to curvature and when changes in curvature affect to energy density? Or can these kind of changes be non-local just as gravity correlated with matter in general? Is orbiting-like repetition needed for causality considered?

I'm studying the principle of locality in physics. But the curvature of spacetime means that the fly-by has momentum of spreaded curvature of meeting bodies and those keep colliding into each other early. Where is the source of the cause? The fly-by anomalies has been mentioned. Are there any fly-by research projects that take the principle of locality into account?

I appreciate answers that focus on localizing the physics so that time travel or any exotic negative energy etc. is left out. My problem is identifying on what basis something is cause or effect with gravity or when it is a non-local correlation of the curvature of spacetime.

For example, gravitational waves act locally, but gravity acts non-locally in general. In which situations do changes in the gravitational field transmit causal information? Especially in fly-by passing: where is the origin of the causal information?

Another case. Point-like fermion particles obey the Pauli exclusion principle. Although they appear to be free, they are subject to field forces and together other particles can "feel" tidal forces - if I interpreted correctly what is meant by "feeling gravity".

Thus, the local limiting flat tangent space must be considered relative to the surrounding other tangent spaces (even if it is also point-like) and real (e.g. em) forces occur. The farther the particles are from each other, the more significant are the changing field effects compared to Decoherent interaction. How much has been loaded into the finished space-time curvature into the future without the exchange of causal local information and energy? Does it depend on the internal structure of the particles or the size, the mass? On the relationship to the dominant curvature?...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Eusa "Gravity acts non-locally in general" -- how so? Gravitational waves are an implication of how gravity acts, which is locally. I think a rudimentary reading on GR (best reference being Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, 1973) would clear these questions.

Comment: Formed curvature needs no information from gravitating bodies if there are no changes - it's non-local correlation due to GR. It's clear how the changes of gravitation propagate from spherical centers of particles. But curvature "dingle" is larger net form (and have momentum as  non-local correlation), in fly-by situation "dingles" meet early and start interacting. I wonder what are causal info and how it's spatially localized and temporally timed as causal phenomenon for all observers. Freefalling test particle on geodesics has no cause for its state of motion - it's coordinates-dependent.

Comment: Yes, this topic will be resolved. I tried to see if I could get a reference here that was just right for the topic - and of course I wasn't completely without benefit.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_structure (see the famous Hawking and Ellis book)

Comment: There is no good consensus in mainstream physics about the causality and locality of gravitational field interactions. The question does not meet the appropriate standards of this site. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This has to do with energy conditions and how the causal structure of the spacetime are linked. While the causal structure is usually somewhat axiomatic, in that the causal principle and satisfaction of the causal conditions are assumed, there is a rather deep link between how energy conditions are violated and how the causal structure are correlated.

While your question is somewhat vague, let me substantiate a statement. When considering solutions to the field equations, one usually considers the possibilities of singularities, for which there is a very precise set of statements having to do with the energy conditions, causal conditions and the geometric aspects of the spacetime. Penrose's 1965 theorem, as a prime example, states that if a spacetime is globally hyperbolic, satisfies the null energy condition, contains a non-compact Cauchy slice and has a closed trapped surface (i.e. one for which both the null expansions in the future are negative), then there exists a null geodesic incompleteness. In a more fundamental sense, this can be attributed to the amount of information passing through the future light-sheet (the null hypersurface of a surface with compact boundary that is compact due to the null energy condition and the Raychaudari equation) of a non-compact surface. In such a case, there must be at least one incomplete null generator so that the covariant entropy bound is satisfied. However, if one assumes that geodesic incompleteness can be competed by a violation of the causal condition, i.e. there exists a closed timelike curve, then this is challenged.

---

**Edit**: Apparently I need to cite some things. See Lobo, 2010; Hawking and Ellis, 1973 and Bousso, 1999.

Comment: Please write substantial answer that details the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the opinions of others.

Comment: @Eusa Which resource? There are several works, which unfortunately are too many to cite. And what opinions are relied upon? I think an elementary understanding of GR works. Maybe see Hawking and Ellis (1973), which in itself suffices. As of the covariant entropy bound, see Bousso's work, titled the same.

Comment: Thanks. I read Bousso's texts and found something useful out of Covariant Entropy Conjecture and Spacelike Projection Theorem...

Comment: @Eusa Ok. I initially also had a bit on Godel's universe, see Lobo's 2010 paper on closed timelike curves and energy conditions for this. This is of course, more or less playing around with numerics. Like I detailed, the information aspect relating energy conditions to physically relevant entropy bounds is more important. See inspire with a generic search for related works on covariant entropy bounds, Wall's singularity theorem using the generalized second law, Bousso-Engelhardt works on holographic screens, etc. for more on things like generalized entropy, marginally trapped surfaces, etc.

Comment: I think that closed timelike loops are metaphysics.